# Is there a way to change user password on IBM System i (aka iSeries / AS400) using SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, passwords, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a C#.NET application that must be able to change the user password on an IBM System i (iSeries / AS400) machine. I am currently using the following code to perform this operation using IBM's proprietary **cwbx.dll**.

```cs
using cwbx;

public void ChangePassword(string system, string user, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
{
    AS400System as400 = new AS400System();
    as400.Define(system);
    try
    {
        as400.ChangePassword(user, currentPassword, newPassword);
    }
    finally
    {
        as400.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAll);
    }
}
```

This works well enough, but forces me (and all users of the application) to take a proprietary dependency on **cwbx.dll**. I would like to eliminate this dependency.

Is there any way to change the password using SQL similar to MS SQL Server's [`alter login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) mechanism?

I know I can accomplish this with the **IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries** .NET data provider by invoking programs from SQL using the following code from [Integrating DB2 Universal Universal 
Database for iSeries with for iSeries with 
Microsoft ADO .NET](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246440.pdf).

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Call a program directly on the iSeries with parameters
/// </summary>
public string CallPgm(string cmdtext)
{
    string rc = " ";

    // Construct a string which contains the call to QCMDEXC.
    // Because QCMDEXC uses single quote characters, we must
    // delimit single quote characters in the command text
    // with an extra single quote.
    string pgmParm = "CALL QSYS/QCMDEXC('"
    + cmdtext.Replace("'", "''")
    + "', "
    + cmdtext.Length.ToString("0000000000.00000")
    + ")";

    // Create a command to execute the program or command.
    iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(pgmParm, _connection);
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (iDB2Exception ex)
    {
        rc = ex.Message;
    }

    // Dispose the command since we're done with it.
    cmd.Dispose();

    // Return the success or failure of the call.
    return rc;
}
```

The problem with this technique is that I must have an existing connection before I can attempt to change a password. Unfortunately, if the user's password has expired they cannot connect to the database (`iDB2CommErrorException`) and as a result cannot change their password.

Is there any way accomplish this without the cwbx.dll?

Comment: If you -1, please at least state why so I can improve the question.

Comment: Could you set up a web page that communicates with (or runs on) the AS/400 for the users to use to change their passwords?

Comment: The application itself must detect the expired password scenario and provide the users with a way to change it, but a web service (rather than a web page) could expose the needed functionality to the application. This would eliminate the dependency, but I was hoping a pure SQL method existed.

Comment: You cannot change a user password on IBM i using SQL. And just to clarify things a bit, the .NET data provider you mentioned creates a connection to the IBM i (not just a connection to DB2 on the i), that's why it is able to invoke programs. That may seem like a trivial difference but it's not. You say you don't want to use this second technique because "...if the user's password has expired they cannot connect to the database..." - if they can't connect to the database how can your cwbx.dll solution work? How can they change their password without first connecting to the IBM i?

Comment: @BennyHill Perhaps, it would have been better to word it "...if the user's password has expired they cannot connect to the **system without an iDB2CommErrorException**...". Regardless, the cwbx solution does work. We have been using it in production code for years.

Comment: The cwbx solution works because, just like a normal 5250 session, the user is allowed to attempt a connection with their expired password and prompted for a new password. Unfortunately it doesn't help us with your problem... what about [these methods](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas10043a8b0e0544f1386256ba100659bcd)? Would any of them work for you?

Comment: @BennyHill Good info, thanks for the link. Telnet and IBM i Access for Web will not work because they are UI based. FTP will not work because login fails for accounts with expired passwords. Java would probably work, but would not be an improvement to the application.

Comment: **Don't do it.** 

Have you seriously considered the potential security issues this could open up if you have hacker attacking your system?
 
This seems like a risk not worth taking.

Comment: I'm not attempting to do anything that can't already be done in numerous ways.  I'm just trying to find out if and how it can be done without taking a dependency on cwbx.dll. Based on responses,  exposing a custom web service  on the IBM i or including a java utility program in the application seem like the best options. I would be happy to award the answer if someone would summarize these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To programmatically change expired passwords on an IBM i (aka System i / iSeries / AS400) from a .NET application without taking a dependency on a local installation of *IBM i Access for Windows* (for cwbx.dll), consider one of the following options.

- Programmatically establish a Telnet connection to the IBM i and transmit a sequence of characters that mimics the user input necessary to perform a change password operation. ***Note that this is insecure without further configuration.**
- IBM Toolbox for Java includes an OS/400 or i5/OS Java class that can be used in Java programs to change passwords. The Java help for the class is available in iSeries Information Center a the following Web site: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/pubs/html/as400/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm

  *The following example demonstrates how to perform a change password operation on an expired password using the **IBM Toolbox for Java**. This can be invoked from a C# program using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("java ChangeIBMiPassword hostname username oldpw newpw");` (assuming appropriate classpaths). Also note that it is possible to use Java API's directly from .NET with the [IKVM.NET library](http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/net2java.html).*

```java
import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400;

public class ChangeIBMiPassword {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 4)
            System.exit(-1);

        String host = args[0];
        String user = args[1];
        String oldpw = args[2];
        String newpw = args[3];

        AS400 sys = new AS400(host, user);  
        try {
            sys.changePassword(oldpw, newpw);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

- Write a secure web service that runs on the IBM i. This web service will accept parameters for username, current password and new password. When a user calls this web service, it will perform the change password operation on behalf of the calling program.
- Write a secure web service that does not run on the IBM i. This web service will accept parameters for username, current password and new password. When a user calls this web service, it will use the cwbx library to perform the change password operation on behalf of the calling program. This does not totally eliminate the dependency on cwbx.dll, but it lowers it to a single system.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas10043a8b0e0544f1386256ba100659bcd

Comment: I implemented a similar program to the code shown, but instead created a runnable JAR file that I can call from the command line. You can download it here. https://github.com/cwg999/AS400PasswordChanger/raw/master/export/AS400PasswordChanger.jar (see the project readme to how to call a runnable jar in windows)

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure or function that invokes CHGUSRPRF. It would need to run under high enough authority (and thereby expose the system to additional risk), but it'd then be easy to interact with SQL. Seems like a very questionable idea.